# opengl - rendering design (beginner)

Tags: opengl

I have a simulation program where I want to render about 500 - 1000 objects (rather small, max 50 triangles) in an animation (let's say 500 timesteps) or interactively (altering one object means recalculating all other objects in the worst case).

What would be the best approach for such a rendreing task?

I was thinking of VBOs and using `glBufferSubData` to update the objects for each timestep. Or is there some other method?

Also, as there are about 20 types of objects should I use 20 different VBOs so I can set up the attributes accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing keyframe animation (one set of vertices per frame), then either upload them all as separate VBOs and change which one you bind, or upload them all in a single VBO and change the attributes. I doubt that there would be much of a performance difference between these two solutions.

I would avoid `glBufferSubData`, since OpenGL should be able to manage all your memory for you. If this were a significantly larger set of data, I would suggest this method as you could stream the vertices you needed from disk to avoid having it all in memory at once, but with a small set of data this isn't an issue.

If you're doing bone-based animation, the `glBufferSubData` method is basically the only way to do it if you're skinning on the CPU. A vertex shader that does skinning (on the GPU) will perform much better than CPU skinning, just store your frames in a `mat3x4` uniform.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing bone-based animation. Ok, I think that's the way to go: pass the reference frame for each object and then let the gpu flesh it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For such a small number of objects, you probably should select the very easiest way to do it and optimize only if you really have to...

And by easy, I mean conceptually easiest for you.

You can use a single VBO object with just different offsets into it if you like, there's no need to use several.